# TextMate: Regex replacing $1 with following 0

Tags: regex, textmate

I'm trying to fix a file full of 1- and 2-digit numbers to make them all 2 digits long.

The file is of the form:

```
10,5,2
2,4,5
7,7,12
...
```

I've managed to match the problem numbers with:

```
(^|,)(\d)(,|$)
```

All I want to do now is replace the offending string with:

```
${1}0$2$3
```

but TextMate gives me:

```
10${1}05,2
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance,
Ross

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [this](http://manual.macromates.com/en/regular_expressions), TextMate supports word boundary anchors, so you could also search for `\b\d\b` and replace all with `0$0`. (Thanks to Peter Boughton for the suggestion!)

This has the advantage of catching all the numbers in one go - your solution will have to be applied at least twice because the regex engine has already consumed the comma before the next number after a successful replace.

Comment: According to that link, $0 is supported, so you can simplify the regex to `\b\d\b` and use 0$0 in the result.

Comment: Even better :) Serves me right not reading it more thoroughly. Edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks Tim,

A very tidy solution.

Comment: And for anyone who tried this with no success in Textmate2 (like me) please check rvm and make sure you are using ruby2.

Answer (score 2):

**Note:** Tim's solution is simpler and solves this problem, but I'll leave this here for reference, in case someone has a similar but more complex problem, which using lookarounds can support.

---

A simpler way than your expression is to replace:

```
(?<!\d)\d(?!\d)
```

With:

```
0$0
```

Which is "replace all single digits with 0 then itself".

The regex is:
Negative lookbehind to not find a digit `(?<!\d)`
A single digit: `\d`
Negative lookahead to not find a digit `(?!\d)`

Single this is a positional match (not a character match), it caters for both comma and start/end positions.

The `$0` part says "entire match" - since the lookbehind/ahead match positions, this will contain the single digit that was matched.

Comment: Thanks. Must play with lookbehind/aheads. I'm a regex n00b.

Answer (score 2):

To anyone coming here, as @Amarghosh [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3084288/20938), it's a bug, or intentional behavior that leads to problems if nothing else.

I just had this problem and had to use the following workaround: If you set up another capture group, and then use a conditional insertion, it will work. For example, I had a string like `<WebObject name=Frage01` and wanted to replace the `01` with `02`, so I captured the main string in `$1` and the end number in `$2`, which gave me a regex that looked like `(<WebObject name=(Frage|Antwort))(01)`.

Then the replace was `$1(?2:02)`.

The `(?2:02)` is the conditional insertion, and in this instance will always find something, but it was necessary in order to work around the odd conundrum of appending a number to the end of `$n`. Hope that helps someone. There is documentation on the conditional insertion [here](http://manual.macromates.com/en/regular_expressions#conditional_insertions)

Comment: Now *there's* a nice feature!

Comment: I was able to use your workaround to put a number after a replacement.  In my case, I didn't really have anything to capture to use for the conditional insertion, so I just did a capturing group on something I knew wouldn't match any characters, and conditionally inserted nothing: `^(.*)(π?)$` replaced by `$1(?2:)0`

Answer (score 1):

In TextMate 1.5.11 (1635) `${1}` does not work (like the OP described).

I appreciate the many suggestions re altering the query string, however there is a much simpler solution, if you want to break between a capture group and a number: `\u`.

It is a TextMate specific replacement syntax, that converts the following character to uppercase. As there is no uppercase for numbers, it does nothing and moves on. It is described in [the link from Tim Pietzcker's answer](http://manual.macromates.com/en/regular_expressions).

---

In my case I had to clean up a csv file, where box measurements were given in cm x cm x mm. Thus I had to add a zero to the first two numbers.

```
Text: "80 x 40 x 5 mm"
Desired text: "800 x 400 x 5 mm"

Find: (\d+) x (\d+) x (\d+)
Replace: $1\u0 x $2\u0 x $3 mm
```

---

Regarding the support of more than 10 capture groups, I do not know if this is a bug. But as OP and @rossmcf wrote, `$10` is replaced with `null`.

Answer (score 0):

You need not `${1}` - replace strings support only up to nine groups maximum - so it won't mistake it for `$10`.

Replace with `$10$2$3`

Comment: When I try this, I find that $10 is replaced with nothing, so:

    25,9,

becomes:

    259,

Comment: @rossmcf This is the normal behavior of replacing with regexes. I don't have textmate, but if you're right, that might be a bug in it.

Comment: @Tim can you confirm if it's a bug or not - the linked page doesn't say anything in particular about the behavior of `$n` if n > 9 - but supporting `$10` doesn't sound like a good idea.